# java - filter log file by regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i need to filter data from log and i need to filter data, that cointains time 13:00-14:59.
but this and many other temptations failed.Nothing is displayed
[Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dt7r.png)

My method :

```
public static void Proccesing(File file){
    String formula = ".*1(3 [0-5][0-9]|4 [0-5][0-9]).*";

    try{
        BufferedReader rd= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = rd.readLine();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(formula);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

        while(line != null){
            matcher.reset(line);
            if(matcher.find()){
                line = rd.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);

            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure why rd.readLine() is inside your if statement and not like this `while((line=rd.readLine()) != null)` or the first line in a do-while loop

Comment: The first time a line is not matched you will have an infinite loop because you are never reading the next line.

Comment: Would you please explain, in detail, what your regex is supposed to be doing? I'm pretty sure that the first and last .* both can and should be removed.

Comment: @user thanks. Its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the logs using Java8 approach:

```
public static void process(String logFile) throws IOException {
    Files.lines(Path.of(logFile))
        .filter(s -> s.matches(".*1(3 [0-5][0-9]|4 [0-5][0-9]).*"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```